# GEB Why is it necessary for TNT-PROOF-PAIR{a,a'} to be represented in TNT?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic, formal-systems

In Hofstadter's [Gödel, Escher, Bach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del,_Escher,_Bach) there is the predicate `TNT-PROOF-PAIR{a,a'}` which is used in constructing the Gödel string.

He then explains that it is a fundamental fact that this is not only *expressed* in TNT but also *represented* in TNT, which means that this predicate is always *decidable* for 2 concrete numerals.

Now why is this fact important? Couldn't the Gödel string be constructed in the same way if the predicate was only expressible and not decidable?

Comment: Just as a heads up, the song T.N.T. by AC/DC is actually written as a self-encoding Gödel sentence for Hofstadter's TNT approach. Also their name is actually a reference to Axiom of Choice/Dependent Choice.

Comment: @AsafKaragila You are taking us on a Highway to Hell there (I can already hear Hell's Bells)

Comment: @Hagen: Well, formally speaking, Hell is Gehenom in Hebrew, which is derived from the Valley of Hinnom or Gehenna. This is a place just outside of Jerusalem. So in reality, what AC/DC were singing about was just being on Route 1 from Tel Aviv to Jerusalem.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ah, cool. And I suppose they also are merely fond of wheather reports (Thunder ...... Thunder .... Thunder ....) :)

Comment: The "construction" on which [Gödel's Incompleteness Theorem](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/#AriForLan) is based needs a *decidable* relation $\text{Prf}(x,y)$ - meaning that $y$ is the G-number of a derivation (in the formal system) of the formula whose G-number is $x$ - in order to build $\text{Prov}(x) := \exists y \text{Prf}(x,y)$  - meaning that there is a derivation (in the formal system) of the formula whose G-number is $x$. In order that the last one is semi-decidable (r.e.), we need decidability of the first one.

Comment: In a nutshell, *representability* of a relation $R(n_1,\ldots, n_k)$ means that (for some $\varphi_R$) : if $R(n_1,\ldots, n_k)$ holds, then $\vdash_F \varphi_R(n_1,\ldots, n_k)$, and if not-$R(n_1,\ldots, n_k)$ holds, then  $\vdash_F \lnot \varphi_R(n_1,\ldots, n_k)$. This fact matches the "completeness" property for the formal system $F$ : for every *sentence* $\varphi$ : either $\vdash_F \varphi$ or $\vdash_F \lnot \varphi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, the Gödel formula could be constructed if the predicate was not represented in TNT, but then TNT would be a weak system and already incomplete because `TNT-PROOF-PAIR{a,a'}` is undecidable, therefore the Gödel construction becomes superfluous.
2. The hope was that a strong system(where `TNT-PROOF-PAIR{a,a'}` is represented/decidable) would provide a decision procedure for any formula because either it is true and therefore a *provable* theorem, or it is false and therefore its negation a *provable* theorem. This is what completeness means.
3. The whole point of the Gödel construction was to prove that even strong systems are incomplete.